# regular expression && || conundrum

Tags: javascript, expression

I would greatly appreciate if someone can please explain why this is. The attached images show a console shot of a Javascript Regular Expression that I was trying after I followed the lesson in conjunction. I was expecting to get all true booleans when using the OR || operator, at least.

regular expression with || operator:

[image: regular expression with || operator]

regular expression with && operator:

[image: regular expression with && operator]

Comment: Please post plain code whenever possible, as reading that screenshot is nearly impossible.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that. Had no idea that the site is gonna shrink them this badly!! It's my second time posting here, and my first attaching an image.

Comment: No trouble! Just giving some advice so more people can help with your questions. Plain text is really nice since people can copy-paste code from your example to test things out, plus it's searchable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A RegExp will always evaluate to `true`, so according to the [logical operator rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
(/Mou/) || (/str/)  //=> /Mou/
```

and

```
(/Mou/) && (/str/)  //=> /str/
```

```js
document.write( (/Mou/) || (/str/));

document.write('<br>');

document.write( (/Mou/) && (/str/) );
```

If what you want to test is the presence of either *"Mou"* **OR** *"str"* in a string then you can use this RegExp which uses the pipe symbol to achieve logical *or* behavior withing a group ([more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)):

```
/(Mou|str)/

// or dynamically constructed:
var a = "Mou";
var b = "str";
var regexp = new RegExp('('+a+'|'+b+')');
```

If what you want to test is the presence of both *"Mou"* **AND** *"str"* then you can use this slightly more complicated construct, which makes use of positive lookaheads ([more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)):

```
/(?=.*Mou)(?=.*str)/

// or dynamically constructed:
var a = "Mou";
var b = "str";
var regexp = new RegExp('(?=.*'+a+')(?=.*'+b+')');
```

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I needed to know!! Thanks a bunch!! I am studying, and after each lesson I try to test & experiment with code to see if I got it right, and to actually see it working. My idea was to see if I can find 2 different strings. My next step would be, if I can manage to get in which var string it was found. This is really super fun; maybe I'm weird!! Thanks again!!

Comment: Glad to know you're discovering the joy of programming. JS has a lot of confusing aspects so don't fret if some things seem weird to you at first.

Comment: YES!!! It became my playing field, sort of...I've tried to study C++ on my own, about 8 years ago, and managed to reach the beginning of the intermediate level...don't know if it is fortunately, or, unfortunately, that I don't remember much of it, as some tutors told me to forget about it when studying the languages I am currently studying (html, css, javascript, jquery & ajax, ruby and rails)

Comment: *>some tutors told me to forget about it*   On the contrary I think it's helpful to begin by a language like C++ which has stricter constructs, because under the hood, JavaScript does much of the same stuff with types, objects, etc.... Just don't assume you know JS because you know C++ because as this question highlights some things that look similar actually work differently.

Comment: oops, forgot to do that!! Well, this is another dilemma now, as I'm not quite sure which of the two answered my question. The one by Matt Ball is super informative and really appreciated all the explanation, and made me realize that I assumed that these operands work "normally" with regex. The one by lleaff just "hit the nail precisely on its head" in terms to what I was trying to achieve. I think at face value the correct answer is by lleaff, but managed to understand why the output is as such, by Matt Ball. Thanks so much to both; greatly & truly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have assumed that `&&` and `||` work to "combine" regex, but boolean operators simply don't work like in JavaScript. [From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

> #### Logical operators
>
> Logical operators are typically used with `Boolean` (logical) values. When they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the `&&` and `||` operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value.

If `a` and `b` are regex objects, then they are both "truthy." For any two truthy values, `a || b` evaluates to `a` and `a && b` evaluates to `b`.

Comment: That's what I needed to know!! Thanks so much!! So, this is something "propriety" to regex only, right?? With the [or] || operator the first is true, and with the [and] && operator the second is true; correct?

Comment: No, the point is that there _is not any regex-specific behavior_ with regard to boolean operators.

Comment: Yes indeed, I assumed that the || && operands works "normally" in regex; which now I know they don't, so normally. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score -3):

Fairly easy to make mistake:

&& and || are called "Short Circuit" operators, they return the second operand based on the value of the first.

http://www.openjs.com/articles/syntax/short_circuit_operators.php

Comment: That's a really terrible JS reference.

Comment: it was the quickest source i found.  I'm not a big JS fan myself, but i did remember those being Short Circuit.  What would you suggest aside from Oracle docs themselves?

Comment: MDN is a good reference however this doesn't seem like a javascript issue but a Regex one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: The fact that the operators short-circuit is irrelevant here. The sentence your answer quotes (_"they return the second operand based on the value of the first"_) is downright incorrect. I would recommend [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) or [the official language spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) (and not Oracle – don't mix up Java with JavaScript!).

Comment: this is a truly "foot in mouth moment", coz I managed to see the comments after!! Seems that linked article created some form of debate between a couple of readers, and it's really interesting...I can see now that the article is incorrect...nevermind though, it's fairly easy to make mistake!!!

Comment: Matt... Looking at section 12.12.3 in the docs you provided show that && and || are indeed short circuit.  a && b will return B if A evaluates to true.  You are correct that I left out that statement A should be a boolean AND evaluation ( or at least evaluate to a boolean equivalent ) but as i've already stated i'm not the most familiar with Javascript.  The issue is that these operands are being used incorrectly in the above example, but my statement is far from wrong.  Thank you for sharing the official specs and in the future try to be constructive and not abrasive, we're all here to help.

Comment: To be perfectly honest with you, I am so thankful to receive help that immediately I needed to thank you before reading your "help"; in your case the provided link. I can't presume to be so fluent in JS to comment on your thoughts, as I'm still beginning with this language. I can see though that there's several conditions that behave "differently" in JS whereas in other languages they behave fairly similar. Thanks again for your help. It is truly appreciated a lot.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude or ungrateful in any way, but after re-reading the above comments & answers I'm getting that the regex "command" doesn't evaluate to a boolean. So, unless I got this all wrong, doesn't regex only give true or false as output, when the "searched-string" is found/not-found ??